# Axios looping promisses and update previous axios response data

Tags: express, axios

How I can wait for all promises to be resolve in order to update the response.data of the first ajax call? (example using swapi.co api)

A simple express .get wrapper. Each /starship list the pilots resource (see comment inside). I want to have full pilots data in my wrapper /api/starships.

```
app.get('/api/starships/', function(req, res){
axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/starships')
 .then(function(response){
    // res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-control');
    //  pilots: [
    //    "https://swapi.co/api/people/13/",
    //    "https://swapi.co/api/people/14/",
    //    "https://swapi.co/api/people/25/",
    //    "https://swapi.co/api/people/31/"
    // ],
    response.data.results.forEach(function(starship, i){
      if (starship.pilots) {
          var promises = [];
          var fullpillots = [];
          starship.pilots.forEach(function(pilot_info, i){
            promises.push(axios.get(pilot_info))
          })

          axios.all(promises).then(function(results) {
              var fullpillots_info = [];
              results.forEach(function(value, i){
                fullpillots_info.push(value.data)
              })
              // ??? how to update 1 response.data with  fullpillots_info
              starship.fullpillots_info = fullpillots_info;
          });
      } else {
          console.log("No pilots")
      }
    });

    res.json(response.data);
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log({"error": error})
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks about right. But your `function(starship, i){...` will not wait for your promises automatically, it will zoom through that forEach before your can blink and send the response before it's ready.

You need to make a `starshipPromises` and push in the promise from `axios.all(...` .and then something along the lines of

```
axios
  .all(starshipPromises)
  .then((starhips)=>{ 
     res.json(starships);
  });
```

Here is a complete async/await version if that's an option:

```
app.get('/api/starships/', async function(req, res){

  const starships = (await axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/starships')).data.results;
  for (let starship of starships) {
    starship.fullpillots_info = [];
    for (let pilot of starship.pilots) {
      starship.fullpillots_info.push( (await axios.get(pilot)).data );
    }
  }
  res.json(starships);

});
```

Comment: ty and double ty for the clean syntax. It was exactly what I was missing.